# Which is a better composition?

Tags: technical-writing

Consider following sentence composed in different ways,

1. And the worst, when memory is full, creation of new node will return a NULL.
2. And the worst is when memory is full and a new node is created because it will return a NULL.
3. And the worst, a NULL is (will be?) returned when memory is full and a new node is created.

The idea is that creating a new node does not return a node but a NULL when memory is full. This might lead to (a) program failure if not handled correctly. To capture this sense, which one of (the) above I should prefer?

Comment: This would be off-topic at English.SE.

Comment: Belongs here, it is an on-topic critique question best phrased as "which of the following best conveys my meaning?"

Comment: This is an older question. It's been bumped by the system because it's been retagged, as per [this](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/534/26) meta post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Of the three options that you offer, I'd say that #1 is the best. However, I'd suggest this as better yet:

> Worst of all, creation of a new node will return NULL when memory is full.

Two things in particular to note:

1. The adjunct clause *when memory is full* reads best at the end of the sentence. Trying to put it earlier requires that you set it off with commas, which reads awkwardly.
2. Beginning with *And the worst* is not exactly incorrect, but it is more idiomatic to say *Worst of all*.

Comment: yes, this is perfect. This is what my brain kept trying to say when I read the post, in fact. :)